# Javascript how to get first div element style and change it

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have below html code,

```
<div id="one">
    <div style="width:100%;height:auto;">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    <div>
</div>
```

**Code used:**

```
let parentDivId = document.getElementById('one').children[0];
console.log(parentDivId);
```

In the above console only i am getting

```
 <div style="width:100%;height:auto;">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
  <div>
```

How to get that first div style using pure java script?

**Note**: no need to add any id's in the the div's.the above html came dynamical

Need to get the first div with inline styles defined. Also i getting the above html inside a js variable.so document.query selector will not work.Please help me.

Answer (score -2):

document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'RED';

The above code uses vanillaJS

Answer (score -2):

The best way to get first nested div is like:
`document.querySelector('div div')`

Then you can assign styles to it like
`document.querySelector('div div').style.color = #fff`